# Printing the value in an address location with a user-defined function and the main function gives me different values

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, multidimensional-array

I was trying to write a function that creates an array of a given shape(with 'a' rows and 'b' columns) and return the base address of that array.

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int *ones(int a, int b){
    int one_arr[a][b], *p;
    
    for(int i=0;i<a;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<b;j++){
        one_arr[i][j] = 1;
    }
    }

    p = &one_arr;
    for(int i=0;i<(a*b);i++){
    printf("%u -- %d\n", p+i, *(p+i));
    }
    return(p);
}

int main(){
    int a=3, b=3,;
    int* p;
    p = ones(a,b);
    printf("\n");

    for(int i=0;i<(a*b);i++){
    printf("%u -- %d\n", p+i, *(p+i));
    }
}
```

output:

```
prog1.c: In function 'ones':
prog1.c:12:11: warning: assignment to 'int *' from incompatible pointer type 'int (*)[a][b]' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   12 |         p = &one_arr;
      |           ^
3772775440 -- 1
3772775444 -- 1
3772775448 -- 1
3772775452 -- 1
3772775456 -- 1
3772775460 -- 1
3772775464 -- 1
3772775468 -- 1
3772775472 -- 1

3772775440 -- 0
3772775444 -- 0
3772775448 -- 0
3772775452 -- 0
3772775456 -- -522191656
3772775460 -- 239
3772775464 -- 1009985511
3772775468 -- 32759
3772775472 -- 1
```

When I tried printing the values in the array using the base address in the function itself(ones), that worked fine. But when I tried displaying the values using the returned pointer inside the main function, it is printing out this garbage.

Comment: `int one_arr[a][b]` is not standard c++.

Comment: C and C++ are two very different languages, no matter how similar they might look. Please pick *one* of them (I assume C since you use constructs that are valid C but invalid in C++, and you named your source-file as a C source file).

Comment: Just use `std::array`

Comment: As for your problem, there are multiple problems: First is that the type of `&one_arr` is `int (*)[a][b]`, not `int *`. The second problem is that since `one_arr` is local inside the `ones` function, its lifetime will end when the function return, and cease to exist. The pointer you return is invalid, and dereferencing it will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Also, for any pointer or array `p` and index `i`, the expression `*(p + i)` is *exactly* equal to `p[i]`. The latter, using `p[i]`, is usually clearer and more easily recognized (and less to write).

Comment: Furthermore, the format specifier to print a `void *` pointer is `%p`. Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to undefined behavior as well. And you *must* cast the pointer to `void *` for it to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Returning a pointer to a local variable is undefined behavior.  You either need pass in the variable and initialize it, or calloc/malloc it.  The comma after 3 is a syntax error.  Don't mix `int *` and int `[a][b]` syntax.  It's two different things.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int *ones(int a, int b) {
    int *p = malloc(sizeof(int) * a * b);
    for(int i = 0; i < a * b; i++)
        p[i] = 1;
    return p;
}

void twos(int a, int b, int (**p)[a][b]) {
    *p = malloc(sizeof(int[a][b]));
    for(int i = 0; i < a; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < b; j++)
            (**p)[i][j] = 2;
}

int main(){
    int a=3, b=3;

    int *p = ones(a,b);
    for(int i=0;i<(a*b);i++){
        printf("%p -- %d\n", (void *) (p+i), *(p+i));
    }

    int (*p2)[a][b] = NULL;
    twos(a, b, &p2);
    for(int i=0;i<a; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<b; j++)
            printf("%p -- %d\n", (void *) &(*p2)[i][j], (*p2)[i][j]);
}
```